# Clojure : list values for a single key

Tags: list, join, clojure

I come from Python world where it's quite easy to do mean/group-by. But I'm programming in clojure and I would like to compute means for each article ID from a big query result.

After having formatted my query result, I have something like that (this is a sample, the result is much bigger) :

```
(def sample 
  '({:Article_ID "123" :Price 233} {:Article_ID "234" :Price 25} {:Article_ID "123" :Price 320}))
```

I would like to have somethink like that first :

("123" [233 320] "234" [25])

That is the idea, the final result would be :

({:Article_ID "123" :Mean 276.5} {:Article_ID "234" :Mean 25})

So I need two steps : list values, then apply mean function. Teh second part sounds ok for me but I'm stucked in the first step : list values.

1) Approach 1

I defined :

```
(defn list-column [query fields]
  (let [values (into {} (map (fn [x] {(x :Article_ID) []}) query))]
    (map clojure.walk/keywordize-keys
      (map (partial zipmap fields) values))))
```

Launched :

```
(list-column sample ["Article_ID" "Values"])
```

So that I have

```
({:Article_ID "123" :Values []} {:Article_ID "234" :Values []} {:Article_ID "123" :Values []}
```

2) Approach 2 :

I also tried

```
(defn list-column [query]
  (into {} (map (fn [x] {(x :Article_ID) []}) query)))
```

To have :

```
("123" [] "234" [])
```

I'm now stuck to the listing part.

1) What is the best approach to compute means ? Do not care about the final format (and it can be changed)
2) How to append each price to each :Values field ?

I think I have to use conj to the append. Maybe assoc for the ID matching but does not know how to put it together (does not know how to bound article_ID from first list to value in second list).

Thanks

EDIT :

Here is the final function to be reused fro general purpose

```
(defn agg-mean-value [query key value]
  (let [init-list (->> (group-by key sample)
     (map (fn [[k v]]
              [k (mapv value v)]))
     (into {}))]
    (map (fn [[k vs]]
           {key k value (/ (reduce + vs) (count vs))})
         init-list)))
```

I will refine it in the future as my knowledge grows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clojure has a [group-by](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/group-by) function that will do the first part I think.

```
(group-by :Article_ID sample)
    => {"123" [{:Article_ID "123", :Price 233} {:Article_ID "123", :Price 320}], "234" [{:Article_ID "234", :Price 25}]}
```

You can calculate the mean like so:

```
(defn mean [vals]
    (/ (apply + vals) (count vals)))
```

We can clean up the group-by like so:

```
(->> (group-by :Article_ID sample)
     (map (fn [[k v]]
              [k (mapv :Price v)]))
     (into {}))
=> {"123" [233 320], "234" [25]}
```

Finally applying the mean functions gives this:

```
(->> (group-by :Article_ID sample)
     (map (fn [[k v]]
              [k (mapv :Price v)]))
     (into {})
     (vals)
     (map mean))

=> (553/2 25)
```

Comment: In general it's a bad idea to use `first` on a (possibly un-ordered) map. You should use `(group-by :Article_ID sample)` instead.

Comment: isn't the last example the same as `(->> (group-by :Article_ID -ample) (vals (map #(mean (mapv :Price %))))`?

Comment: That looks about the same. There are a lot of ways to unpack this problem.

Comment: It might have some syntax problems though.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works fine. I'm exploring the language and try several things. Did not understand how ->> worked but here it's very clear.

Answer (score 2):

I usually prefer to use a `reduce` to do grouping of values. It can be less readable, but I have more control over the output. As for this specific problem, I will admit that you are not getting a ton of value out of using `reduce` (as opposed to `group-by`), but I thought I would post anyways.

```
(def groups
  (reduce
    (fn [m {:keys [Article_ID Price]}]
      (assoc m Article_ID (conj (get m Article_ID []) Price)))
    {}
    sample))
```

This will give you just a hashmap of keys and vectors:

```
=> {"123" [233 320], "234" [25]}
```

From there you can map over your groups:

```
(map (fn [[k vs]]
       {:Article_ID k :Mean (/ (reduce + vs) (count vs))})
     groups)
```

and produce the results you wanted:

```
=> ({:Article_ID "123", :Mean 553/2} {:Article_ID "234", :Mean 25})
```

Comment: Thanks too, I mixed both answers to make a reusable general function for big query queries !